# The mysqlclient nightmare

Tags: python, mysql, centos

I am trying to install mysqlclient in a centos system. These are some of the issues I am facing:

- `mysqlclient` needs to be compiled in the installation system
- to compile it, according to the [official sources](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python#install), we need `python-devel` and `mysql-devel`
- what if I am installing `mysqlclient` in a `virtualenv` with `python36`? Do I need `python36-devel` instead of `python-devel`? Why is this not mentioned in the documentation?
- will `python36-devel` match the `python36` of my `virtualenv`? What if I am using my self-compiled `python37` instead of the centos `python36`, will that match `python36-devel`? It's not like I have infinite options regarding the centos packages I can install ...

And some problems unrelated to `mysqlclient`, but related to `centos`:

- `centos` does not have `python36` by default. It seems something called `epel-release` must be installed.
- `python36-devel` installs 36 (!!) dependencies:

--

```
Installed:
  python36-devel.x86_64 0:3.6.8-1.el7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

Dependency Installed:
  dwz.x86_64 0:0.11-3.el7                   groff-base.x86_64 0:1.22.2-8.el7          perl.x86_64 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6         perl-Carp.noarch 0:1.26-244.el7                 perl-Encode.x86_64 0:2.51-7.el7               perl-Exporter.noarch 0:5.68-3.el7       
  perl-File-Path.noarch 0:2.09-2.el7        perl-File-Temp.noarch 0:0.23.01-3.el7     perl-Filter.x86_64 0:1.49-3.el7        perl-Getopt-Long.noarch 0:2.40-3.el7            perl-HTTP-Tiny.noarch 0:0.033-3.el7           perl-PathTools.x86_64 0:3.40-5.el7      
  perl-Pod-Escapes.noarch 1:1.04-294.el7_6  perl-Pod-Perldoc.noarch 0:3.20-4.el7      perl-Pod-Simple.noarch 1:3.28-4.el7    perl-Pod-Usage.noarch 0:1.63-3.el7              perl-Scalar-List-Utils.x86_64 0:1.27-248.el7  perl-Socket.x86_64 0:2.010-4.el7        
  perl-Storable.x86_64 0:2.45-3.el7         perl-Text-ParseWords.noarch 0:3.29-4.el7  perl-Time-HiRes.x86_64 4:1.9725-3.el7  perl-Time-Local.noarch 0:1.2300-2.el7           perl-constant.noarch 0:1.27-2.el7             perl-libs.x86_64 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6     
  perl-macros.x86_64 4:5.16.3-294.el7_6     perl-parent.noarch 1:0.225-244.el7        perl-podlators.noarch 0:2.5.1-3.el7    perl-srpm-macros.noarch 0:1-8.el7               perl-threads.x86_64 0:1.87-4.el7              perl-threads-shared.x86_64 0:1.43-6.el7 
  python-rpm-macros.noarch 0:3-24.el7       python-srpm-macros.noarch 0:3-24.el7      python3-rpm-macros.noarch 0:3-24.el7   redhat-rpm-config.noarch 0:9.1.0-87.el7.centos  zip.x86_64 0:3.0-11.el7
```

Utterly broken, if you ask me.

Comment: Try `yum install MySQL-python`. But this question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @mvp: `django` requires `mysqlclient`

Comment: Compiling everything from source is not for faint of heart. You will have better luck with installing ready to use rpms, e.g. from here: https://pkgs.org/download/python-django

Comment: @mvp not a good option for me. I am running in a virtualenv, and not installing system wide.

Comment: @mvp what would be good is a pre-compiled wheel of `mysqlclient` for `amd64` + `python36`. I do not know if such a thing exists.

Comment: You just mentioned that you installed python36 system wide. What makes django any different?

Comment: @mvp `python36` installed system wide in order to bootstrap a `python36` virtualenv. Actually, in my real system I am using my self-compiled `python` binary, so not really installed from centos repos. But the description I gave is enough to highlight the issues I am having. Which can be summarized as: "compiling `mysqlclient` against a non official python version is a nightmare (and even against an official `python36`)"